# Coolant leaking rear of engine/bellhousing area. Head gasket leak?

Tags: cylinder-head, coolant-leak

I have a 1998 GMC Savana with a 5.7L v8. I was losing coolant so I went underneath and saw little droplets near the oil pan. I would park the car for a week and come back and all the coolant would be gone. The oil looked clean and oil pressure is normal. The exhaust wasn't blowing any smoke, so I assumed it was the water pump. Today I went to look at the engine and saw coolant on the right side near the head/bellhousing area. The other side is completely dry. The fluid looked pinkish which was the colour of my coolant. I don't think it is oil. Is this most likely a head gasket leak or is there something else in that area that could've caused this?[image]

The left side completely dry:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head Gasket or an intake manifold leak, intake is more likely on that year model, a pressure test will find it for sure.